# Using ES6 features in Expressjs, Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i've been trying to use ES6 features in Express. I read that Nodejs now has natively supports es6 so I don't need babel to do anything for me.

Within my `app.js` file I have:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const shell = require('shelljs');
const fs = require('fs'), gm = require('gm');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const app = express();
// view engine setup
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bundle'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
// app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

I then have my `server.js` file which just basically runs http server and points to my `app.js` no errors within my `server.js` file. However, I am using es5 in there.

```
Path/To/Project/app.js:3
const express = require('express');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Path/To/Project/server.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
NAME-MacBook-Pro%
```

I removed the `'use strict';` from the top of the file as it complained but just got another error with `unexpected token`.

Do I need to use babel to compile it down or something? Why's it complaining?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of nodejs you are using?

Comment: That was embarrassing. I was using V0.12.0, upgraded to V5.0.0 now. Works fine!

Comment: I was expecting that, since I walked into the same trap. :-) Happy coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using an old version of node. You have to have version 4+ to be able to use ES6 features like `const`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need use to all features of es6, its better to compile using [`babel`](http://babeljs.io/) first. As even `Node v5.0.0` implements only 59% of ES6 features as of today.

Check [this](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) link for ES6 compatibility table.

Answer (score 0):

`const` will still continue complaining as in even in ES6 const has been shipped as block scope. And your are using it here outside block.

Please go through [this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) for more details

Comment: Yeah, I would of thought it would of worked anyway. Cause I declared it globally